# Prove that a $d$-regular, $d$-edge-connected graph $G$ is tough when $d\geq3$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness, graph-connectivity

Isn't something like shown below can happen where $d=3$ and $k=1$?
If no, then how do we prove it.
[image]

Here v is a vertex with degree $3$, and $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$ are $3$ different components, then removal of $v$ leads to $3$ components.
If $C_1=C_2=C_3=C$ and $C$ is given by the image below.
[image]

And $v$ is connected to vertex $u$ of each $C_i$.

Question - Let $d\geq3$ be an integer, and let $G$ be a $d$-regular graph (every vertex has degree $d$) which is $d$-edge-connected.Prove that such a $G$ is tough, meaning that removing any $k$ vertices disconnects $G$ into at most $k$ connected components (for all $k \geq1$).

Comment: You have to show more effort in order for the SE community to be willing to help you. What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: @b00nheT I have given a counter example with a picture. let C1=C2=C3=C, then there exists a C which is connected!

Comment: @b00nheT I have even added description of each Ci for more information please look at it.

Comment: Your example is not a counterexample because this graph is not $3$-edge-connected.

Comment: @Batominovski okay now i see it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a $d$-regular, $d$-edge-connected graph, and suppose that deleting vertices $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k$ from $G$ leaves connected components $U_1, U_2, \dots, U_m$.

For every $i \in \{1, 2, \dots, m\}$, because $G$ is $d$-edge-connected, there must be at least $d$ edges from $U_i$ to its complement. But since $U_i$ is a connected component of $G - \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$, these edges cannot go to any other connected component $U_j$. Therefore there must be at least $d$ edges from $U_i$ to $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$.

Altogether, we get at least $md$ edges between $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup \dots \cup U_m$ and $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$. However, because $G$ is $d$-regular, there can be at most $kd$ edges with an endpoint in $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$. Therefore $md \le kd$, or $m \le k$.

This is exactly the definition of toughness: deleting $k$ vertices from $G$ left at most $k$ connected components.